# Java type not needed?

Tags: java

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

is equivalent to:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap();
```

And I'm honestly not sure why. I get the casting of the HashMap to a Map, what I don't understand is the lack of types provided to the HashMap. Is a Java 8 addition (some kind of compilation inference)?

Comment: Java 7 addition actually. Some sprinkling of syntactic sugar.

Comment: it's not equivalent, you need to add `new HashMap<>()`

Comment: In the question, i don't see a diamond operator but a raw declaration